# How to display form fields even if the iterated array is empty?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
Question Updated:
```

I am using codeigniter, The problem that i'm having is that, if the array contains values then the form elements will show. if the array is empty the entire form will not show. so imagine this as a edit form where a person has selected to edit a record. and lets say for whatever reason the record that is being edited has no records, its completly empty. and lets also say the id must be visible and be editable regardless of it being empty or not. so what happens is if the record is empty the entire form elements will not show. so what i'm trying to do is have it display regardless if there are records or not.

```
<?php

//controler

public function show()
{
    $this->load->model('my_model');

    $data = array(
        'data' => $this->my_model->getdata();
    );
    $this->load->view('somepage', $data);
}



//model
public function my_model()
{
    $q = $this->db->get_where('some query', array('id' => $id));
    if($q->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        foreach($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }
}





//view
//note: this will only work if the array has data, otherwise everything between the foreach statement wont show.
<?php foreach($data as $row) : ?>

<input type="text" name="something" value="<?=$row->column1;?>">
<input type="text" name="something" value="<?=$row->column2;?>">
<input type="text" name="something" value="<?=$row->column3;?>">
<input type="text" name="something" value="<?=$row->column4;?>">
<input type="text" name="something" value="<?=$row->column5;?>">


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your view

```
<?php
if (!empty($data)) {
    var_dump($data);
} else {
    //print out nothing
}
?>
```

or you can do following

```
<p><?= (!empty($data)) ? $data : "" ?></p>
```

Comment: its pretty much the same thing i've been doing but the else statement does nothing and therefor wont display the records. i've revised my question to show you want i'm trying todo.

Comment: please post here a view, so question is crystal clear

Comment: i was querying tables that should've been joined together as separate tables and one of the tables didn't have a reference id and was completely empty. and i knew this but was trying to see how i can do it otherwise. Since i saw this as a bad idea i initially just inserted a reference id to the empty table so when it came to joining them i would get an output. thanks for your help :)